# Why does tf2.2.0ver even though i did 'import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
print(tf.__version__)
```

result(print): 2.2.0

how can i use tensofrlow 1 version?

Comment: are you doing this local computers,if yes,you should better switch to virtual env and install Tensorflow 1.0 on that one,otherwise in cloud,you can install tensorflow 1.0 using pip

Comment: You _cannot_ use TensorFlow 1.x with a TensorFlow 2.x installation. `tensorflow.compat.v1` is just a compatibility layer to make it easier to write code compatible with both TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x (or to port from 1.x to 2.x). It is not "TensorFlow 1.x within 2.x", and indeed you don't have a `contrib` package in there, as you would in TensorFlow 1.x. The `__version__` string is `2.2.0` because the version is still that. If you want an actual 1.x version, you need to install it explicitly.